# Weird ClassNotFoundException in WebLogic 10.3.6

Tags: spring, hibernate, weblogic

We have an .ear file that is running normal in a WebLogic 10.3.6 application server.
The .ear uses Spring 3.0.5 and Hibernate 3.5.2.

If we deploy the same .ear file in another WebLogic 10.3.6 server, we get the next error.

```
org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext
SEVERE: Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'filterService': Autowiring of fields failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private nl.surf.adapter.generic.dao.MessageFilterDAO nl.surf.adapter.generic.service.FilterService.messageFilterDAO; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/domain-config.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private nl.surf.adapter.generic.dao.MessageFilterDAO nl.surf.adapter.generic.service.FilterService.messageFilterDAO; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/domain-config.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/domain-config.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration
```

I've tried several solutions:

- Place hibernate3.jar in .war/WEB-INF/lib (all jars are now in .ear/lib)
- Use <prefer-web-inf-classes>true</prefer-web-inf-classes> in .war/WEB-INF/weblogic.xml

Nothing seems to work.
I'm kind of lost here...

Comment: Solved the problem myself.
Can't answer yet, so answer follows tomorrow.

Comment: I see in the exception thrown, hibernate annotation bootstraping is missing in web.xml. Right?

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue with Velocity.  I'm interested in the approach to get around this NoClassDefFoundError issue for org/apache/velocity/app/VelocityEngine.

Answer (score 1):

After some extensive searching on the web and trial and error changes on the .ear, i've found the solution for my problem.

I've changed file META-INF/weblogic-application.xml and added the tags beneath inside tag <weblogic-application>

```
<prefer-application-packages>
  <package-name>org.apache.*</package-name>
  <package-name>antlr.*</package-name>
</prefer-application-packages>
```